# The Number of 3-letter {X,Y,Z} words with no Adjacent Z's.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, trees

Let $a_n$ denote the number of character strings from the alphabet S = {X, Y, Z} of length n with no two adjacent letters being Z's. Find a recurrence relation model of the number of words.

**HINT**
(Sorry the hidden feature is not working.)

> ! To start n=0 is 1 due to the empty set.
>
> ! n=1 is 4  three valid solutions {X}, {Y}, {Z} and the previous empty set.
>
> ! n=2 is 12 8 valid solutions {XX,XY,XZ}; {YX,YY,YZ}; {XZ,XY,***<s>ZZ</s>***} and the previous n=1.

Comment: This is similar to asking, how many ternary terms are there, with a length of n having no adjacent 0's. Use recurrence relations.

Comment: If $a_n$ is the number of strings of length $n$ with no two adjacent Zs, then $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 3$, and $a_2 = 8$ (since there are $3^2 = 9$ strings of length $2$ and all but ZZ are admissible).  Are you having difficulty constructing a recurrence relation?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I do have trouble expressing the recurrence relation. And you are correct up to $a_2$, although $a_2$ should include $a_1$ and $a_0$ for a total of 12. I can explain the process, and accurately predict the next iteration, but I cannot express the solution as a recurrence relation. I also thought it was a pretty cool problem, and wanted to pose it to the rest of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a recursive relation in two variables. Let $a_n$ denote the number of strings of length $n$ that begin with $Z$, and $b_n$ denote the number of strings of length $n$ that begin with $X$ or $Y$.

We then have:

$$a_{n+1} = b_{n}$$
$$b_{n+1} = 2(a_n + b_n)$$

where the first relation is obtained because for each string of length $n+1$ that begins with $Z$, we may adjoin a string that begins with $X$ or $Y$ to it, and for each string of length $n+1$ that begins with $X$ or $Y$, we may adjoin any string of length $n$ to it.

EDIT: Solving the recurrence.

We consider the two relations above in matrix form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\2 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_{n}\\b_{n}\end{bmatrix}$$

So the characteristic equation of the coefficient matrix, as well as the sequences $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ is

$$\begin{vmatrix} -\lambda & 1 \\ 2 & 2-\lambda \end{vmatrix} = \lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 2 = 0,$$

which gives roots $\lambda_{1} = 1 + \sqrt{3}$ and $\lambda_{2} = 1 - \sqrt{3}$.

Solving the general formulae for $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ by substituting the first two values yields

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}( (1+\sqrt{3})^n - (1-\sqrt{3})^n)$$
$$b_n = \frac{1}{6}((3+\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{3})^n + (3-\sqrt{3})(1-\sqrt{3})^n)$$

Summing the two yields a formula for strings of length $n$. If you wish to compute the number of strings of length $n$ or less, just substitute the two formulae above into

$$c_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k + b_k)$$

I'm sure you can get a cleaner answer, but this is all I have to say...

Comment: You must indeed solve the recurrence. This is similar to the way I expressed the solution.

Comment: Okay, I'll type it up after work!

Comment: Just solved the recurrence

Comment: That is the exact answer I got! Thank you!